# PXE Booting a Raspberry pi 4

Tags: 64-bit, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pxe, tftp

I have a PXE and TFTP Server in a VM and want to Boot a Raspberry Pi 4 with it.
I want to serve a RaspberryOS image to the pi4 because I don't want to use a sd-card for it.
How do I need to configure the Servers to archive this?
The Server is based on Ubuntu 22.04 and DNS mask is installed on it.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working for you? You can take a look through https://medium.com/jacklee26/set-up-pxe-server-on-ubuntu20-04-and-window-10-e69733c1de87 for ubuntu examples, though note that you can usually just do the DHCP settings on your router installing of installing dhcp on the server

Comment: I want to set up a PXE server so that Raspberry PI 4 can boot from the network. 
VM : PXE server 
Raspberry PI 4 : Client without sd card. 
What configuration does it need to boot Raspberry PI from server instead SD card.
So live_ image for Raspberry PI.

Comment: Did you read through the linked article? It has all the steps. There is too much to cover in one answer here. The main server configurations are HTTP pointing to `pxelinux.cfg` menu and TFTP image file paths